# Radon-Nikodym derivative for linear combination of measures

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives

Given $(X, A, z)$ is a finite measure space, and for fixed $n$, $A_1, A_2,\ldots, A_n\in A$ such that $A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n\in R$ be distinct, and for $B\in A$, define $p(B) = \sum_{m=1}^{n} a_m\ z(B\cap A_m).$ Compute the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dp}{dz}$.

Any thought on how to proceed after proving $p$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $z$ would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by writing $pE$ as an integral.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got till this: $p(B) = a_m \sum_{m=1}^{n}\int_{B\cap A_m} \chi_{A\cap A_m}$. Now, the key trouble is how to find a function $f$ such that we can rewrite the linear combination RHS as $\int_{E} f$?

Comment: I added an answer below, is this sufficient to help you proceed?

Comment: Many thanks copper.hat. I got $f = \sum_{m=1}^{n} $a_m 1_{A_m}?

Comment: That is correct :-).

Comment: I'm dumb:P Thanks for your help, copper.hat!

Comment: No. It is a reasonable question.

Comment: @copper.hat: Did you use Fubini theorem so that you can move the summation inside the integral? And this theorem applies in this case because $\sum_{m=1}^{n} a_{m} 1_{A_m}$ is bounded by sum of all $|a_i|$, and $A$ is finite measure. Is this a correct argument? 

In addition, since we fixed $n$, $\cup_{m=1}^{n} B\cap A_m$ is not guaranteed to be $B$. So, the countable additivity of integration does not apply. So, how did you obtain the final integral of $p(B)$ over $B$?

Comment: The integral is linear, so for finite sums you have $\int \sum_k f_k = \sum_k \int f_k$. No Fubini needed.

Comment: The summation inside the integral might blow up, so I think we do need Fubini. Anw, can you address the 2nd part of my question, since it's a key part?

Comment: As I mentioned, the integral is linear so it can't blow up on finite sums, so we do not need Fubini. There is no countable additivity issue. I don't know what you are referring to by the second part?

Comment: You're correct:) The second part is this: from $z(B\cap A_m) = \int_{B\cap A_m} 1_B 1_{A_m} dz$, how come $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \int_{B\cap A_m} 1_B 1_{A_m} = \sum_{m=1}^{n}  \int_{B} 1_{B} (\sum_{m=1}^{n} a_m 1_{A_m})$?

Comment: I added some notes to the answer. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but your clarification is not quite helpful, because the way did not indicate on which set the integral takes place. Can you confirm if all of those integrals are over set $B$? We have to indicate this clearly so that the integral could make sense.

Comment: The integral is over the whole space $X$. This is what is usually meant by $\int f dz$. Also, it is usual to **define** $\int_B f dz = \int 1_B f dz$.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your patience!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @copper.hat: can you please help review my solution to another problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763657/conditions-on-integrable-function-with-counting-measure?noredirect=1#comment3600281_1763657. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $z(B\cap A_m) = \int 1_B 1_{A_m} dz$.

Hence $pB = \int 1_B(\sum_m a_m 1_{A_m}) dz$.

Clarification:

Note that $1_{A \cap B} = 1_A \cdot 1_B$, and so $1_{B\cap A_m} = 1_B \cdot 1_{A_m}$.

$pB = \sum_m a_m z(B\cap A_m) = \sum_m a_m \int 1_B 1_{A_m} dz =  \int 1_B(\sum_m a_m 1_{A_m})  dz = \int 1_B g dz$, where
$g = \sum_m a_m 1_{A_m}$.