# conditions on integrable function with counting measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $P(N)$ be the power set of $N$ and $u$ be the counting measure on $N$.

(a) Prove or disprove the measure space $(N, P(N), u)$ is complete?

(b) Given function $g: N\rightarrow R$. Show that $g$ is integrable if and only if $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} g(m)$ is absolutely convergent.

**My attempt:** For (a), I was able to show that due to definition of $u$, the only set $E\in N$ with $u(E) = 0$ is the empty set. And the empty set belongs to $P(N)$, thus the measure space $(N, P(N), u)$ is complete.

For (b), by using two results: (1) "For nonnegative, measurable function $f$ in the measure space $(N, P(N), u)$, we have: $\int_{N} f du = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$, and (2) "f is integrable iff $|f|$ is integrable," we apply it with the function $g$ (note that $g$ is always $u$-measurable in the given measure space), then it's sufficient to show that $|g|$ is integrable iff $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} |g(n)|$ is absolutely convergent. By using result (1), since $\int_{N} g du = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} |g(n)|$, we're done.

Can someone please help review if my solutions above is correct, especially for part (b). The result (1) is quite strong, since it doesn't require $f$ to be integrable at all (in fact, if $f$ is not integrable, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ is divergent, but the equality still holds).

Comment: Your solution to (b) is OK. For item (a), you argument needs to be improved. Here is a suggestion on how to solve item (a)

(a) Suppose $A \in P(\mathbb{N})$ and $u(A)=0$. We must prove that if $B\subseteq A$, then $B \in  P(\mathbb{N})$ and $u(B)=0$.  Suppose $B\subseteq A$. Clealy we have $B \in P(\mathbb{N})$. Since $u(A)=0$, we have that $A=\emptyset$, and since  $B\subseteq A$, we have $B=\emptyset$ and so $u(B)=0$.

Comment: @Ramiro: Thank you very much for your help. I think due to the fact that the ONLY set $E\in N$ with $u(E) = 0$ is an empty set, then any subset of an empty set is just an empty set itself, so it's pretty much equivalent. But you're right that I should be more clear:)

For part (b), do you really think it's fine? I'm afraid because (1) doesn't need the condition that $f$ is integrable, so I'm not sure if the equation in (1) is allowed for non-integrable function?

Comment: Equation (1) is valid for any nonnegative measurable function $f$. If $f$ is integrable then $\int f du <+\infty$.

Comment: Here is a suggestion for rewording your proof for item (b): Note that $g$ is always $u$-measurable in the given measure space. We know that (1) $g$ is integrable iff $|g|$ is integrable.  We also know that "For nonnegative, measurable function $f$ in the measure space $(N, P(N), u)$, we have: $\int_{N} f du = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ and $f$ is integrable iff  $\int_{N} f du <+\infty$". So we have that (2) $|g|$ is integrable iff $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |g(n)| <+\infty$. It follows immediately from (1) and (2) that $g$ is integrable iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(n)$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Ramiro: yeap, your rewording proof is much better than mine, so thanks a ton for that:) But I'm truly glad that equation (1) is true regardless of integrability of $f$:)